# Кто знает как создать таких кнопок?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно создать таких кнопок для моего проекта... то есть нужно создать такой стиль. 
я попробовал, но не получается сделать так, если знаете помогите))

Comment: если пробовали то приложите код, как именно пробовали. Здесь нет экстрасенсов.

Comment: Есть!(нет,просто предположение) Скорее всего это обычный Button с приминением shape и gradient, ну или картинка как фон

Comment: Вот код на drawable: <selector 
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#AAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#EF771A"
                android:endColor="#EE814D"
                android:angle="270"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>